# Kafka-Connect JDBC Sink Connector and Avro Fails on Second insert

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to follow a basic JDBCSinkConnector example based on the tutorial from Confluent. the Sample uses MySql Database with an Avro Topic and a schema-registry.

The sample works for the first message that arrives in the topic and inserts the data to MySQL table correctly, however for the second message I get the error "could not find schema with id 26"

1. started with creating the sink job :

```
{
  "name" :"mySqlTest5",
  "config": {
   "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "connection.user":"root",
    "connection.password":"some-password",
    "topics":"orders",
    "tasks.max":1,
       "auto.create":true,
    "connection.url":"jdbc:mysql://some-url",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://dp-cp-schema-registry:8081",
    "insert.mode" :"upsert",
    "pk.mode" : "record_value",
    "pk.fields": "id"
    }
}
```

2. Then sending the first message to the topic :

```
kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list kafka:9092 \
--topic orders3 \
--property schema.registry.url=http://schema-registry:8081 \                                       
--property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"orders","fields": \
[{"name":"id","type":"int"},{"name":"product", "type": "string"},
{"name":"quantity", "type": "int"}, {"name":"price",
"type": "float"}]}'
```

after the producer is ready for user input I enter :

```
{"id": 999, "product": "foo", "quantity": 100, "price": 50}
```

This inserts the item successfully to the Database!

3. while the console producer still waits for user input I enter the second message :

```
{"id": 101, "product": "bar", "quantity": 200, "price": 70}
```

which causes the following exception:

> >
>   Error retrieving Avro schema for id 26
>   connect-server Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
>   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:230)
>   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:256)
>   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:323)
>   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:311)
>   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getVersionFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:184)
>   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getVersion(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:297)
>   at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.schemaVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:202)
>   at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:158)
>   at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:243)
>   at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(AvroConverter.java:134)

I do not understand why the first message is inserted correctly and also produces a subject in the schema-registry (/subjects/orders-value) with the correct Id, but the second insert fails.

**UPDATE :**
for some reason the schema data in the avro message container an extra field (schema.registrey.schema.version=1)
the original schema does not include this field but it appears on the logs :
 Sending POST with input {"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"statuses\",\"namespace\":\"my.namespace\",\"fields\"[…] \"schema.registry.schema.version\":1}"} to http://dp-cp-schema-registry:8081/subjects/mySubject?deleted=true (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService)
which process in the pipeline is adding this “schema.registry.schema.version” field ?